# Variant of the lights out problem

Tags: matrices

Given an $n \times n$ binary grid, initially set to the zero matrix, what's the shortest number of steps one can use to get to the matrix of all ones, if subject to the following condition on transitions: the only transformation allowed is picking an entry and flipping it, which causes all eight adjacent bits to flip.

I haven't been able to glean any illuminating structure from this problem to even take a stab at a solution.

Comment: If $n$ is divisible by 3, it's easy: just flip all nine bits of a 3x3 square in turn in the obvious way.

Answer (score 0):

$\left(\left\lfloor\dfrac{n+2}{3}\right\rfloor\right)^2$ flips suffice.

Strategy: for $n=3k$, treat the matrix as $k^2$ $3\times3$ squares and flip the centre of each square ($k^2$ flips). For $n=3k-1$, add $6k+1$ marshmallows along two adjacent edges as fake lights to turn it into the $n=3k$ case ($k^2$ flips). For the $n=3k-2$ case, add $12k+4$ marshmallows in a border around the entire grid  to turn it into the $n=3k$ case ($k^2$ flips).

The strategy is obviously optimal for the $n=3k$ case. I suspect an argument for optimality can be made for the other cases by arguing that for any pair of overlapping flips at least one further flip is required.